# Fabric Service availability on start

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a scenario where one of our services exposes WCF hosts that receive callbacks from an external service.

These hosts are dynamically created and there may be hundreds of them.  I need to ensure that they are all up and running on the node before the node starts receiving requests so they don't receive failures, this is critical.

Is there a way to ensure that the service doesn't receive requests until I say it's ready?  In cloud services I could do this by containing all this code within the OnStart method.

My initial thought is that I might be able to bootstrap this before I open the communication listener - in the hope that the fabric manager only sends requests once this has been done, but I can't find any information on how this lifetime is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "fabric manager" that controls network traffic between your services **within the cluster**. If your service is up, clients or other services inside the cluster can choose to try to connect to it if they know its address. With that in mind, there are two things you have control over here:

The first is whether or not your service's endpoint is discoverable by other services or clients. This is the point at which your service endpoint is registered with Service Fabric's Naming Service, which occurs when your ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync method returns. At that point, the service endpoint is registered and others can discover it and attempt to connect to it. Of course you don't have to use the Naming Service or the ICommunicationListener pattern if you don't want to; your service can open up an endpoint whenever it feels like it, but if you don't register it with the Naming Service, you'll have to come up with your own service discovery mechanism.

The second is whether or not the node on which your service is running is receiving traffic from the Azure Load Balancer (or any load balancer if you're not hosting in Azure). This has less to do with Service Fabric and more to do with the load balancer itself. In Azure, you can use a [load balancer probe](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/) to determine whether or not traffic should be sent to nodes.

EDIT:
I added some info about the Azure Load Balancer to our documentation, hope this helps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/

Comment: Thanks vaclav. Just to clarify, if I open my service hosts before I call OpenAsync, it won't receive traffic automatically from azure because it's not discoverable via the naming service? or is that wrong? If not i'll have to check out the load balancer feature.

Comment: No, the Azure Load Balancer doesn't know about Service Fabric, the Naming Service, or your application layer, it only knows about the VMs. When you set up your cluster in Azure, you specify "custom endpoints" which are the ports on the cluster VMs that you want to expose through the load balancer - this is all the load balancer knows about. Unless you add probe rules, which the load balancer then uses to test if a VM can accept traffic on a certain port, but again this is all at the VM level.

Comment: Thanks Vaclav, that clears that up (and thanks for the guide).  What worries me is that since I have no control over opening the port on the VM that the probe will direct traffic to my Service before it's ready - how often do they get probed? just trying to figure out how to handle this - will probably have to re-architect something.